# VOIP phone dialer

Tags: python-3

What would the best way be to connect to my PBX or to dial a number to PBX?

I'm really lost where to start. looking to use python3 with some softphone maybe

Comment: We're going to need more details about what you need for us to help. What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to do it? What have you already tried?

Comment: Where is the problem with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I need to know where to start! I haven't done anything yet except getting the rpi.

Comment: I want to dial a code to my PBX when a button is being pushed, I have it working when a user dials a number on their phone a sound is playing. I want to do that when a button is pushed on the raspberry pi.